# VCR fails with DB (cassettes table doesn't exist) error when running tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vcr

While using [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) with my Rails 3.1 app on Ruby 1.9, running `rake test` with an existing cassette produces:

> Error: test_#create_returns_created_account_upon_successful_creation(AccountServiceTest)
>     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'test_db.vcr_cassettes_account_service_create' doesn't exist: DELETE FROM `vcr_cassettes_account_service_create`

My VCR config in my **test_helper.rb**:

```
 VCR.configure do |c|
   c.allow_http_connections_when_no_cassette = true
   c.cassette_library_dir = 'test/fixtures/vcr_cassettes'
   c.hook_into :fakeweb
 end
```

Applicable Test::Unit code:

```
require 'test_helper'

class AccountServiceTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test '#create returns created account upon successful creation' do
    VCR.use_cassette('account_service_create') do
      created_account = AccountService.new.create({name: 'honeybadger'})
      assert_equal 'honeybadger', created_account.name
    end
  end
end
```

FYI, I'm also using DatabaseCleaner; not sure if there's a conflict there. Anyone seen this before?

**NOTE: This passes when the VCR cassette does not exist yet**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what's happening is that something is trying to rebuild or revert everything in your `test/fixtures` directory;  And its trying to revert everything in `vcr_cassettes` as well, which doesn't exist.

Moving my `vcr_cassettes` to a directory outside of `test/fixtures` solved this for me.

1) Delete the `test/fixtures/vcr_cassettes` directory

2) And change your `test_helper.rb` to:

```
c.cassette_library_dir = 'test/vcr_cassettes'
```